# How to handle value changing

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm trying to set value on another (supplierPriceWithDiscountSpinEdit) SpinEdit control when changing value in first (supplierDiscountPercetangeSpinEdit) SpinEdit by handling event:

```
private void supplierDiscountPercetangeSpinEdit_EditValueChanging(object sender, 
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal supplierPrice, supplierDiscount, supplierPriceWithDiscount;

            supplierPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(supplierPriceSpinEdit.EditValue);
            supplierDiscount = (decimal)e.NewValue;
            supplierPriceWithDiscount = Discount.DoMath(
                supplierPrice, supplierDiscount);

            supplierPriceWithDiscountSpinEdit.EditValue = Convert.ToDecimal(
                supplierPriceWithDiscount);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw; // Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
        }

    }
```

This method work's well when I'm using Up & Down buttons on control, but on keypress exception is thrown with message Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Probably problem is line : `supplierDiscount = (decimal)e.NewValue;`

Comment: I assume it does not like `(decimal)e.NewValue`.  Did you set a `breakpoint` to see what `e.NewValue` is at that point?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the ValueMember is decimal?

Comment: Trace and be sure which line.  Write e.ToString().   Come on do some debugging before posting.

Comment: If I press "1" then e.NewValue is "1.00" object{String}. When using control buttons it's decimal as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot cast string to decimal have to parse

```
decimal supplierDiscount = decimal.Parse("1.00");
```

Comment: But for parse has to be string and e.NewValue is object?

Comment: Come on apply yourself e.ToString()

Comment: This was CultureInfo issue, had to set `percentage = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your question on the previous line:

```
supplierPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(supplierPriceSpinEdit.EditValue);
```

You are in the handler `supplierDiscountPercetangeSpinEdit_EditValueChanging`, which I can only assume handles the `EditValue` property change of a `SpinEdit` object. Thus `e.NewValue` reflects that property value. The above is handling the same property, so naturally you should handle this one the same way:

```
supplierDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValue);
```